# Kill all Programs on a specific display

Tags: linux, bash, xorg

does anyone know how to kill all Programs on a specific X display?

In example, I need to kill all Programs on Display :1. How is this possible?

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: Bash Script - would be nice if this could be solved with built in commands ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
xkill -displayname :1 -all
```

quoth the [manual](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xkill/):

> This  option  indicates that all
>   clients with top-level windows on the
>   screen should be killed.  Xkill will
>   ask you  to  select the  root  window
>   with each of the currently defined
>   buttons to give you several chances to
>   abort.   Use  of  this  option  is
>   highly discouraged.

and:

> This command does not provide any
>   warranty that the  application  whose
>   connection  to  the X server is closed
>   will abort nicely, or even abort at
>   all. All this command does is to 
>   close  the  connection  to  the  X
>   server.  Many  existing applications
>   do indeed abort when their connection
>   to the X server is closed, but some
>   can choose to continue.

Answer (score 0):

`xlsclients` lists all clients with windows on the screen, and `xkill` kills them.

Why do you need this?

Comment: Im trying to build a screenshot factory for browsershots.org and i want to optimize the screenshooting process